# How come Debian has no time(1) manpage?

Tags: time, man

Searching for manpage for `time` command does not yield any result ([search form](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?manpath=Debian%20unstable%20sid)).

As a sidenote, it appears to be a BASH built-in command since `dpkg --search bin/time` cannot find it. Perhaps such commands don't have their own manpages?

Comment: Use `type time` or `type -a time` to see whether you time command is a shell built-in or a separate executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, usually shell built-ins have `help` pages instead since their usage isn't usually that involved. If the built-in commands *were* all that complicated, there would have likely been an effort to simplify shell logic by pushing that functionality into its own executable, at which point it *would* get a man page.

You can get information on `time` by using `help time`

```
[jadavis6@ditirlns01 ~]$ help time
time: time [-p] PIPELINE
    Execute PIPELINE and print a summary of the real time, user CPU time,
    and system CPU time spent executing PIPELINE when it terminates.
    The return status is the return status of PIPELINE.  The `-p' option
    prints the timing summary in a slightly different format.  This uses
    the value of the TIMEFORMAT variable as the output format.
times: times
    Print the accumulated user and system times for processes run from
    the shell.
```

Since your example is `bash`, for GNU tools, you might also try `info <toolName>` to get more exhaustive information. `help` is designed to be ran on the command line, and they don't want to flood your screen (possibly pushing useful information off screen) so they try to keep `help` short and give you the full spiel in the info pages. For example:

```
[jadavis6@hypervisor ~]$ info time
```

**<...after I hit enter, an ncurses page appears...>**

```
File: time.info,  Node: Top,  Prev: (dir),  Up: (dir)

   This file documents the the GNU `time' command for running programs
and summarizing the system resources they use.  This is edition 1.7,
for version 1.7.

* Menu:

* Resource Measurement::  Measuring program resource use.

 -- The Detailed Node Listing --

Measuring Program Resource Use

* Setting Format::      Selecting the information reported by `time'.
* Format String::       The information `time' can report.
* Redirecting::         Writing the information to a file.
* Examples::            Examples of using `time'.
* Accuracy::            Limitations on the accuracy of `time' output.
* Invoking time::       Summary of the options to the `time' command.

The Format String

* Time Resources::
* Memory Resources::
* I/O Resources::
* Command Info::
```

Fully describing info pages is probably out of the scope of your question, so I'll leave it at that. I only mention it so you're aware of their existence.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. Shell built-ins are covered under their shell's man pages, since no appropriate discrete man section exists for them.

Comment: There is also an external `time` binary, but may not be installed by default.